# Compiling and linking of a C program

Tags: gcc, ld

I am learning about compiler linker and loader and was trying to understand the working of linker and loader on my ubuntu 12.04 machine

I wrote 2 simple ".c" files as follows

test.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%d",test_fun(10));
}
```

test2.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int test_fun(int a)
{
  return a*10;
}
```

Then I executed following commands

```sh
cc -c test.c

cc -c test2.c

ld test.o test2.o -o a.out -lc --entry main
```

Now in my current directory a.out file is generated. I can see the file when I type `ls` but when I try to run the file as

```sh
./a.out
```

I get error

```sh
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me?

Comment: Short answer? Try using `gcc -v` to compile something. Long answer, read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/c-programming-how-to-link-with-glibc-using-ld-903088/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you can make an answer from your comment. Just explain why not use `cc` and `ld`.